# zend 2: Variable containers in view templates with Zend\Form

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework2

I'm reading a book on ZF2 "Using Zend Framework 2" and saw something that confused me.

It was an example of using Zend\Form in a standard MVC style app where a variable is injected into a view like normal:

```
return new ViewModel(array(
    'form' => $form
));
```

But in the template it does this:

```
<?php
   $form = $this->form;
   $form->prepare();
?>
```

Why is $this->form being assigned to a local variable? I can just do $form->prepare() and it *looks* like it works. If I just call $form->prepare() does it not permanently modify the $form variable container? Do you have to copy it to a local variable first before calling prepare()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for reading my book. This is just for convenience. The `$form->prepare()` looks shorter than `$this->form->prepare()`. These two ways are absolutely equivelent.

Comment: Hmm think I might have marked this as the answer to early. My confuse is that I can just do $form->prepare() with ever even using $this and it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: When I do var_dump($this->form); and var_dump($form); looks like I get back the same object, but I can't do $form()->openTag($form); I have to do $this->form()->openTag($form); instead. Might ask a separate question about this cause I'm realizing its a more general question about how variable containers work.

Comment: @user1028270, the php renderer `extracts()` the view variables into template scope, allowing you to use `$form` instead of `$this->form`, you can use either, but IIRC `$this->form` is more expensive since it requires a magic __get() call. Regarding your concern about them being different objects, objects are passed by reference, so `$this->form === $form` anyway, and you can call prepare on either, you're affecting the same object. (I should add using `$form = $this->form;` in the view is pretty redundant)

Comment: But why must I do this $this->form()->openTag($form); instead of just $form()->openTag($form);?

Comment: In that context you're calling the `form` view helper which helps render your form instance, `$this->form !== $this->form()`, view helpers are plugins of the view.

Comment: Yes just realized that after I asked the question. I get it now thanks.